# Is it possible to suspend execution of a process in a docker container at build time and resume at run time?

Tags: docker

I have a docker container where a server takes ~20s to boot up initially because it needs to do a lot of setup, but then it serves requests quickly.

This has been fine so far deploying webapps on AWS App Runner as the startup time is a one-off, but we are considering transitioning the service to lambda to increase scalability and are hitting an issue where that 20s boot is done on every lambda startup.

As all of the work for the boot stage can be done without serving any requests, I'd like to be able to do the boot part during docker build and then resume the executable during docker run to actually process & serve the request.

Is this sort of pattern/setup possible? Thanks!

Comment: Depends on what your application is actually doing. The way the question is phrased, it's a no. You cannot *suspend*  and *resume* a process. That doesn't mean there isn't a solution to your problem. But I think we cannot help you without further details.

Comment: Thanks! The application is the purescript compiler, and I'm loading around 50mb of pre-compiled files at startup time, but then each incremental compilation is quite fast. So the goal is to somehow bake loading of 50mb of data into the build phase so that that could be preloaded when the executable starts.

Comment: If you mean by loading, that you load it into memory, then I guess you cannot do this at build time.  You probably need to try to do lazy loading at runtime, if possible. Or lambda is not the right choice for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in Docker directly supports this.  If your application is able to create a snapshot of itself then this could be theoretically possible, but it'd work the same way inside Docker and without.

As a specific example of this, the Emacs text editor preloads much of its Lisp source at build time and then [dumps the processed code](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Building-Emacs.html), so that it doesn't have to reload the Lisp source at every startup.  This is a very long-standing feature of Emacs, dating back decades before Docker existed.  The mechanics of this are very specific to the program, though.

> I have a docker container where a server takes ~20s to boot up initially...

I wouldn't consider this exceptional; in the space where it'd be nice if it started faster, but probably wouldn't cause operational problems.  I normally expect the standard `postgres` or `mysql` database images to take 30-60 seconds to start up, and I routinely work with things with runtimes that take about that long to load.

> I'm loading around 50mb of pre-compiled files at startup time...

You might see if you can restructure your application to preprocess this data into a form that's faster to load.  Binary formats like protobuf or CBOR can be faster than reading JSON or XML or parsing text files, for example.

In Docker space this could be a reasonable use of a multi-stage build.  Giving a hypothetical example of a Java application that could precompile files somehow:

```sh
FROM openjdk AS app
COPY app.jar /

FROM app AS precompile
WORKDIR /data
COPY *.json .
RUN java -cp /app.jar com.example.Preprocess -o data.bin *.json

FROM app
COPY --from=precompile /data/data.bin /data.bin
CMD java -jar /app.jar -precompiled-data /data.bin
```

Comment: He wants to run it as lambda. So each time it's called it needs a cold start. Then 20s are very problematic.

Comment: I see, oof.  I think it's still the case that there's not a generic Docker solution.  :-/